# Function Int32.TryParse("23.0") returning false - C# MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

In my code i try to get browser version for charging the good css file, but this code doesn't work, and i don't see my error...

I've simply try first with a Convert.ToInt32 but don't works too...

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.logged = false;
            ViewBag.BrowserName = Request.Browser.Browser.ToString();
            Int32 v = 0;
            string version = Request.Browser.Version;

            if (version != null)
            {
                bool result  = Int32.TryParse(version, out v);
            }
            ViewBag.BrowserVersion = v;
            return View();
        }
```

In my debugger :

```
version => string : "23.0"
v => int 0
result => false
Request.Browser.Version => string "23.0"
```

Comment: Why not using a float ?

Comment: This is **by design**

Comment: @Vladimir "23.0" is a string but can be transform to int normally...

Comment: `HttpBrowserCapabilities.MajorVersion` would do the trick for you if that's all you need.

Comment: @fmgp i don't use float because here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1682/Detect-the-browser-using-ASP-NET-and-C , explain that return int or decimal

Comment: Various Parse/TryParse functions throughout .NET expect the input string to contain only string representation of the object being parsed and nothing else, and will return error if they encounter something unexpected, like decimal point when parsing int. Andrei Rinea has the correct solution, use `System.Version`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fully agree with [Andrei's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18536505/390819); that's the approach you should take.

However, I think it's important to note that there *is* a way to parse `int` values from strings such as `"23.0"`: it can be done using [this overload of `int.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27.aspx) which allows you to pass [`NumberStyles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) flags as parameters.

Concretely, after executing this code:

```
int v;

var wasParsedOK = Int32.TryParse(
    "23.0",
    NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint,
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    out v);
```

`v` will hold the value `23` and `wasParsedOK` will be `true`.

Answer (score 3):

This is by design.

Parsing a version string would work better with [System.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx).

You can, alternatively, parse it to a float and then see if a lossless conversion to Int32 can be made.

Comment: Neither of those solutions will work in all situations since browsers can report version strings that include non-digit characters, such as `7.0b`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assume that the version string is going to be integral, or even decimal. A browser could perfectly report `7.0b` as its version. None of `int`, `float`, `decimal` or `System.Version` can represent this.

If you're only concerned about the major and minor version numbers, you can use the [MajorVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.majorversion.aspx) and [MinorVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.minorversion.aspx) properties of your `Browser` object, assuming it is of type `HttpBrowserCapabilities`. The framework has done the parsing for you, so it should be reliable.

Answer (score 1):

It is giving false because *23.0 is not an int*, So you can try with decimal,double or float.

```
decimal v = 0;
string version = "23.0";

Decimal.TryParse(version, out v);
```

Comment: With decimal it was te same problem, but parse int truncate the number so int isn't the problem i think... thx

Answer (score 1):

It's been almost 2 years and no one has answered this correctly. The question is simple, "Why is it returning false?"

This question has already been answered, simply because your string is not an Integer, but is a Double or Decimal. By design, TryParse will try to get the EXACT match of the type integer from your string, if not it will return false, and your string ("23.0") is not an exact match.

Now if you're trying to find a solution in converting your version string to a number, What you can do is filter out the non-numeric, excluding 1 dot (.), in the string, then convert what's left to decimal/double. After this conversion you can then try converting it integer. Since you already converted your stirng to double/decimal, you can no longer use TryParse because the parameter needs to be in string format. You can then use Convert.ToInt32 inside a Try block.